# Can anyone freely call the `tokenFallback()` function in ERC223?

Tags: solidity, tokens, security, erc-223, wallet-contracts

Since the function seems to always be implemented as public, can't an unfair user just call the `tokenFallback()` function of a receiver contract?

That way one could let contracts believe that they received the appropriate amount of money, when they actually haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tokenFallback` function in a token receiver contract can be called by anyone, but as explained in the [ERC223 standard documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223),

> NOTE: msg.sender will be a token-contract inside the tokenFallback function. It may be important to filter which tokens are sent (by token-contract address). The token sender (the person who initiated the token transaction) will be _from inside thetokenFallback function.

So the `tokenFallback` function assumes that the address of the contract which is calling it is the address of a Token contract. There is no way to fake msg.sender, meaning there's no way to trick it into thinking you are a token contract.

Comment: Since fallback splitted into `receive()` and `fallback()` the function `tokenFallback` is renamed into `tokenReceived`.